# How can I filter the results of a database of addresses based on their distance from a specific address?

Tags: mysql, geolocation, maps

I have a database of local businesses on my website.

Essentially i need to add a feature where the user can enter their address and a "max distance" filter and only have results within that max distance from their address returned.

Which library/program/api/ has the capabilities i require?

I have researched the google maps api and it is not feasible, given that their quotas on distance matrix calculations are incredibly restrictive, at 2500 elements per day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "spatial" capabilities of your database. If you database server does not support it, try to find a "spatial" plugin for it. I don't know if with mySql is possible. With SQL Server and with PostGIS.

If your database is SQL Server 2008 for example:

Add a "geography" field to the address table and add a point with the geographic coodinates (latitude, longitude) of each local business:

```
INSERT INTO @addressTable (GeographyColumn) VALUES (geography:STGeomFromText('POINT(longitude,latitude)' , 4326))
```

(the value 4326 means WGS84 coordinate system (that's used by your GPS))

Then when quering create an object with the coordinates of the client:

```
DECLARE @client geography
SET @client = geography::STPointFromText('POINT (longitude, latitude)', 4326)

SELECT * 
FROM addressTable
ORDER BY Location.STDistance(@client)
```

Comment: MySQL has built in spatial support. I think it would be an overkill for this simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get latLong of both addresses (using geoCoding on google maps api), Then you can compare them with mysql query.
Check this [Google search page](http://goo.gl/95IQr) for a list of Stack Exchange questions about how to 
points within specified distance or distance look-up.